# TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run it, it gives me the error:

> TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator, not a list. You can either cast it to a list:

```
columns = list(zip(*rows))
float_columns = [map(float, col) for col in columns[1:]]
```

use `itertools.islice` to select everything but the first element,

```
from itertools import islice

columns = zip(*rows)
float_columns = [map(float, col) for col in islice(columns, 1)]
```

or skip the first element with `next()`:

```
columns = zip(*rows)
next(columns, None)  # skip the first column
float_columns = [map(float, col) for col in columns]
```

Note that `map()` returns an iterator as well, not a list. That may be fine for your purposes.

If you wanted to find the max of each column, for example, you can combine that:

```
columns = zip(*rows)
next(columns, None)  # skip the first column
max_columns = [max(map(float, col)) for col in columns]
```

Comment: it was actually the elements i needed to convert to float. because i need to find their max value. i'm going to try your tips :)

Comment: Thanks! :-) Moved the link to the generic Python 3.x version.

Comment: hmmm they are not working.since i need to find the max value of every column, i need them to be in a list.i didn't know that about map().

Comment: @shaghayeghtavakoli: `max()` takes an *iterable*, so the result of `map()` will do.

Comment: Agneta k 34 0.1 100 0.4 1000 1 0.9  
Adam m 54 0.1 110 0.2 23 1 0.8  
Adolf b 71 0.3 105 0 43 0 0.7
.
.
.
this i what my text file looks like.all the numbers in front of the names represent something and need to find the max value of each of them.so i thought i put every element with the same index number, in a list and then find their max.

Comment: You can still make it into a list, just replace `max()` with `list()` in my last example.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Python 3, in which zip returns an iterable, not a list.

So, by converting it into a list, you can solve your problem.

```
columns = list(zip(*rows))
```

Also, You can skip the first column in the below manner, in which case, you can remove the slice.

```
columns = zip(*rows)
next(columns, 0)
```